# ¿Cömo cambiar el estilo de un div que se crea dinámicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

Hola tengo varios `divs` que se crean dinámicamente, es decir, no están inicialmente en el código sino que con angular `ng-repeat` se crean varios divs con la clase `box-header` quisiera cambiar sus propiedades cada vez que le hago clic pero no funciona,  el  código en otra plantilla `HTML` si funciona bien pero en este caso no. ¿Me podría decir alguien que estoy haciendo mal?

mi **script.js** dice lo siguiente;

```
    var open = 0;
$('#este').click(function () {
    if (open === 0) {
        $('#este').css({
            'border-radius': '0px 0px 43px 43px / 0px 22px 40px 40px',
            'background-color': '#555454',
            'color': 'white',            
            'margin-top': '5%',
            'padding': '3px',
        });
        open = 1;
    }  else {
        if (open===1) {
            $('#este').css({
                'border-radius': '0px 0px 43px 43px / 0px 22px 40px 40px;',
                'background-color': 'white',
                'color': 'black',
                'margin-top': '5%',
                'padding': '3px'
            });
            open=0;}
    }
});
```

Y el **HTML** que genera las listas:

```
       <div class="row" style="display:block; margin-top:-95px" ng-controller="lista_claves">
           <center>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
 <div class="box box-solid collapsed-box" id="oficinas" ng-repeat="item in claves">
//aqui hago click para cambiar propiedad --> <div  class="box-header" data-widget="collapse">
      <img class="liq" src="css/galeria/zoom.png" style="float:left; width:14px; height:18px; margin-left:2%; margin-top: 3%"/>
                                <h2  class="box-title cortar" id="target2"  style="float:left; margin-left:2%;"> {{item.documentos}} </h2>
                                <img class="change4" src="css/galeria/down.png" style="float:right; width:7%;margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 4%;" />
     </div>
                            <div class="box-body" id="uniq" ng-controller="detalle_referenciacontrol">

                                <input type="text" id="twit" ng-model="searchinput" readonly value="{{item.descripcion}}" placeholder="{{item.descripcion}}" cloack  />      
                                <center>
                                    <table class="table table-hover" style="margin:auto">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr style="float:left;" ng-repeat="item in itemsarchivo | filter:{tipodescrip:searchinput}" id="{{item.path}}" onclick="ver(this)">
                                                <td><b class="cortar" style="float:left;">{{item.nombre}}</b><img src="css/galeria/doc.png" style="float:right"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </center>
            </div>
```

Comment: aun no has podido resolver tu pregunta?

Comment: Aun no eh podido resolver, arme un controlador pero solo cambia un elemento de los que tengo :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que logro entender según tu pregunta lo que quieres hacer es agregar propiedades `css` a un `item` cuando este `true` o en su defecto `false`, para esto yo te recomiendo hacer uso de `ng-class` de `angularJs` agregando una clase cuando sea `true` o agregando otra cuando sea `false`, o no agregar ninguna clase, a continuación veras un ejemplo para que te hagas una **IDEA** de como funciona y como puedes trabajarlo, lo que no entiendas me preguntas.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    
$scope.claves =  [
        {
            "documentos": "Sin clasificar (1)",
            "clave": "0",
            "descripcion": "Sin clasificar"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Pedimento Aduanal (3)",
            "clave": "2",
            "descripcion": "Pedimento Aduanal"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros) (4)",
            "clave": "3",
            "descripcion": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Cuentas de Gastos MOZ (2)",
            "clave": "4",
            "descripcion": "Cuentas de Gastos MOZ"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "COVE (4)",
            "clave": "5",
            "descripcion": "COVE"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias) (1)",
            "clave": "6",
            "descripcion": "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias)"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte (1)",
            "clave": "25",
            "descripcion": "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte"
        }
    ]        
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
<!-- Plotly.js -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .item-open {
                border-radius: 0px 0px 43px 43px / 0px 22px 40px 40px;
                background-color: #555454;
                  color: white;            
                  margin-top: 5%;
                  padding: 3px;
            }
            .item-close {
                border-radius: 0px 0px 43px 43px / 0px 22px 40px 40px;
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
                margin-top: 5%;
                padding: 3px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
         <div class="row">
            <center>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box box-solid collapsed-box" id="oficinas" ng-repeat="item in claves" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red; margin-bottom: 50px;" ng-init="item.open = false">
                        <div class="box-header" data-widget="collapse" ng-click="item.open = !item.open" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; position: relative;" ng-class="{'item-open' : item.open}">
                            ejemplo
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Lo que hice fue agregar un `ng-init` e iniciar una variable en `false` `item.open = false`, luego en el `div` hijo del `ng-repeat` agregamos el `ng-click` `ng-click="item.open = !item.open"` donde decimos que cuando le demos `click` a un `item` este va cambiar de `false` a `true` y aplicara la clase `item-open`, esto sucede en el `ng-class` `"{'item-open' : item.open}"` donde decimos que agregue la clase `item-open` cuando `item.open` sea `true` y si es `false` pues no agregue ninguna `clase`.
Otra cosa que puedes hacer es agregar el `item-close` al `ng-class` de esta manera `ng-class="{'item-open' : item.open, 'item-close' : !item.open}"` pero entonces todos los `div` del `ng-repeat` van a tener la clase `item-close` ya que la variable `item.open` es `false` ya que así lo tenemos en el `ng-init="item.open = false"`.
[**Puedes revisar la documentación del ng-class**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: eres un crack funciono muy bien y es esactamente lo que buscaba, ahora mismo ando leyendo la documentacion del ng-class y me sirve para otros asuntos ademas! te lo agradezco mucho! @TheVicious

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer uso de la directiva `ng-click`

```
 //aqui hago click para cambiar propiedad 
 <div id="este"  class="box-header" data-widget="collapse" ng-click="myFunc($event,item)">
```

Dentro de tu Controller

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('lista_claves', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.open = 0;
    $scope.myFunc = function($event,item) {
    var elem = $event.currentTarget || $event.srcElement;
    if ($scope.open === 0) {
               $(elem).css({
                  'border-radius': '0px 0px 43px 43px / 0px 22px 40px 40px',
                  'background-color': '#555454',
                  'color': 'white',            
                  'margin-top': '5%',
                  'padding': '3px',
          });
    $scope.open = 1;
    }  else {
        if ($scope.open===1) {
            $(elem).css({
                'border-radius': '0px 0px 43px 43px / 0px 22px 40px 40px;',
                'background-color': 'white',
                'color': 'black',
                'margin-top': '5%',
                'padding': '3px'
            });
             $scope.open=0;
         }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: se ve genial voy a probarlo

Comment: alli lo edite, cambie nombre de variables.

Comment: Hola funciona pero solo funciona con el primer div  a los demas les doy click y solo prende y apaga el primer div de los 8 que tengo , alguna sugerencia para que funcione con todos?

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar eventos jQuery con elementos dinamicos, debes usar `on()`.  Algo asi:

```
$('#oficinas').on('click', '.box-header', function () {
  if (open === 0) {
    $('#este').css({
        'border-radius': '0px 0px 43px 43px / 0px 22px 40px 40px',
        'background-color': '#555454',
        'color': 'white',            
        'margin-top': '5%',
        'padding': '3px',
    });
    open = 1;
  }  else {
    if (open===1) {
        $('#este').css({
            'border-radius': '0px 0px 43px 43px / 0px 22px 40px 40px;',
            'background-color': 'white',
            'color': 'black',
            'margin-top': '5%',
            'padding': '3px'
        });
        open=0;}
  }
});
```

Comment: hola @alanfcm lo intente de varias maneras y no funciono ):